# How do I transfer the array to the routing parameter?

Tags: arrays, angular, parameters, angular5, angular6

*I'm making a angular project (version 6+).
I want to transfer array parameter, using routing.
*

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {
    path: 'books',
    component: BookComponent
  }
  ,
  {
    path: 'books/:id',
    component: BookDetailComponent
  },

...
```

Comment: send JSON data via routing params is not good approach, either save it in localstorage or call HTTP in navigated page

Comment: Can you please share some snippet of code that you have tried or please elaborate your question.

Comment: Sorry.
If there is a code " userIDs = [1,3,4] " in .ts file

In html, I want to use routerLink in button tag

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
  [routerLink]="['/order', userIDs >
          buy
</button>

Comment: @SangminKim You should update your question as per above comment so other expert can understood easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can use,

### *Method 1:*

**HTML**

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home', userIDs.join()]">Home</a>
```

**TS:**

```
userIDs: Array<number> = [1, 3, 4];
```

**Home component typescript:**

```
export class HomeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  userIDs: Array<number> = [];

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute)   { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.userIDs = params['ids'].split(',');
    });
  }    
}
```

**Router Module:**

```
 path: 'home/:ids', component: HomeViewComponent }
```

### *Method 2 (Using queryParams):*

You don't need to add anything into router module as we are doing in above method.

**HTML**

```
<a routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home']" [queryParams]="{ids: userIDs}">Home</a>
```

**TS**

```
userIDs: Array<number> = [1, 3, 4];
```

**Home component typescript:**

```
export class HomeViewComponent implements OnInit {
  userIDs: Array<number> = [];

  constructor(private router: ActivatedRoute)   { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(p => {
        this.userIDs = p.ids;
    }); 
  }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Welcome, glad to help you. @SangminKim

Answer (score -1):

In html
send data
here first You will import the activated route like following.
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

and also in construction
construction(private _routes:ActivatedRoute) { }

In======   ngOnInit( this._route.params.subscribe(params => {
this.id=param['id'];
)